# Android Application:Error "Found text"

Tags: android, xml, image

I have been following a book on Android "Beginning Android Application". I have been trying to figure out an application which shows images in a view. But unfortunately I could not run the application because of the following errors:

```
[2012-04-24 19:37:33 - Gallery] F:\eclipse workspace\Gallery\res\values 
\attrs.xml:2:error: Found text "
[2012-04-24 19:37:33 - Gallery] â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹    " where item tag is expected
```

For convenience I am giving here the codes.
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Bilai"
/>
<Gallery
android:id="@+id/gallery1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>    
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image1"
android:layout_width="320px"
android:layout_height="250px"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

This application requires another xml file. It is named as attrs.xml under res/values.
attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
​<declare-styleable name="Gallery1" >
​​​​<attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
​​​</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I think the problem lies within attrs.xml, but I dont know whats going on. And because of this the R.styleable also doesnt work either. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look for non-printable characters in `attrs.xml`. If you have copy-pasted the contents of that file, try to delete the contents and type in the contents manually.

Comment: thanks :) yeah i copy pasted that from the book, but couldn't figure out why that would be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have some characters before each line in your attrs.xml due to a copy/past method.

Can you try to reformat your code by placing your text cursor at the beginning of each line and delete to return to previous line ?