# error: Found text: Â Â in strings.xml [Android]

Tags: android, xml

I have this error in the strings.

```
[2014-10-16 22:28:03 - Hotelus] C:\Users\Isuma\Documents\workspace\Hotelus\res\values\strings.xml:63: error: Found text "   Â Â 
[2014-10-16 22:28:03 - Hotelus] " where item tag is expected
```

I do a clean but with no success, recopy and paste dont works, close eclipse either.

I simply cant ged rid of this error.

I checked the spaces in the begening and the end of the file but there is no spaces u.u

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Hotelus</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_login">Login</string>
<string name="email">Email</string>
<string name="contra">Contraseña</string>
<string name="entrar">Entrar</string>
<string name="olvido_contra">Olvidaste tu contraseña?</string>
<string name="registro">Registrate</string>
<string name="dir">Dir.</string>
<string name="tel">Tel.</string>
<string name="mail">Email.</string>
<string name="recordar">Recordarme</string>
<string name="title_activity_sign_up">Sign_up</string>
<string name="usuario">Nombre de Usuario</string>
<string name="nombre">Nombre</string>
<string name="apellido">Apellido</string>
<string name="telefono">Telefono/Celular</string>
<string name="registro_titulo">Registro</string>
<string name="finalizar">Finalizar</string>
<string name="iniciar_sesion_link">Iniciar Sesión</string>
<string name="apellido1">Primer Apellido</string>
<string name="apellido2">Segundo Apellido</string>
<string name="cedula">Cedula</string>
<string name="usuario_login">Usuario</string>
<string name="repite_contra">Repite Contraseña</string>
<string name="country_prompt">Escoja una ciudad</string>

<string-array name="country_arrays">
    <item>Arauca</item>                             <item>Armenia</item>
                                                      <item>Barranquilla</item>
                                                      <item>Bogota</item>
                                                      <item>Bucaramanga</item>
                                                      <item>Cali</item>
                                                      <item>Cartagena</item>
                                                      <item>Cucuta</item>
                                                      <item>Florencia</item>
                                                      <item>Guaviare</item>
                                                      <item>Ibagué</item>
                                                      <item>Inirida</item>
                                                      <item>Leticia</item>
                                                      <item>Manizales</item>
                                                      <item>Medellín</item>
                                                      <item>Mitú</item>
                                                      <item>Mocoa</item>
                                                      <item>Monteria</item>
                                                      <item>Neiva</item>
                                                      <item>Pasto</item>
                                                      <item>Pereira</item>
                                                      <item>Popayán</item>
                                                      <item>Puerto Carreño</item>
                                                      <item>Quibdó</item>
                                                      <item>Rioacha</item>
                                                      <item>San Andres</item>
                                                      <item>Santa Marta</item>
                                                      <item>Sincelejo</item>
                                                      <item>Tunja</item>
                                                      <item>Valledupar</item>
                                                      <item>Villavicencio</item>
                                                      <item>Yopal</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your content was copied from elsewhere, you may have some non-printable characters in your file. Refer to this question: [Android Application:Error "Found text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299646/android-applicationerror-found-text)

Comment: This gave me an idea, so I copy/paste my code into Microsoft Word then I select mantein only text, then just copy/paste back in the file and works!!! :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

just try to change "ñ" for "n" and error should disappear, after that just use google how can you put "ñ" into your XML file

Comment: Nope, didn't work, I also remove the (´) Acute accent but nothing